# Resque front-end doesn't load in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, resque

I've set up the Resque-web interface to work with my rails 3 app but it doesn't work in either development or production environments. My set up is as follows, and going to localhost:3000/resque just gives me the 404 page I've set up.

**Routes.rb**

```
mount Resque::Server.new, :at => "/resque"
```

**Resque initializer**

```
require 'resque'
require 'resque/server'

if Rails.env.development?
  uri = URI.parse(ENV["REDISTOGO_URL"])
  Resque.redis = Redis.new(:host => 'localhost', :port => '6379')
else
  uri = URI.parse(ENV["REDISTOGO_URL"])
  Resque.redis = Redis.new(:host => uri.host, :port => uri.port, :password => uri.password)
end

Dir["#{Rails.root.to_s}/app/jobs/*.rb"].each { |file| require file }
Resque::Server.class_eval do
  use Rack::Auth::Basic do |email, password|
    user = User.authenticate( 'foo@bar.co.za', 'password' )
    user && user.admin?
  end
end
```

Comment: Is your `mount` call inside the route block? or just at the end of the file?

Comment: It's inside of the block, before I specify match '*a' to errors#routing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a route that matches `'/:name'` to a `'model#index'` route must be confusing Resque so I've just mounted it to `'/resque/web'`

Answer (score 3):

My `routes.rb` file has:

```
require "resque/server"

MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
  # routes and stuff

  mount Resque::Server.new, :at => "/resque"

  root :to => 'page#welcome'

end
```

Maybe you forgot the `require` inside the `routes.rb` file?

I do not have a resque initializer, so I don't know if that is causing your problem or not.

Comment: I'm calling `require` from my initializer.